# On If Statement Insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make an if statement that inserts something specific into MySQL database when user clicks submit. But for some reason its not working i think my if statement below is wrong but im not sure how to phrase it. `if($_POST and $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){`
 What do i put here properly to make it so that if the user presses submit it inserts this into the db?

```
if($_POST and $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){ 
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        $$k = $v;
    }
    foreach($cat as $k=>$v){
        if($v =='') continue;
        dbConnect("INSERT INTO twit_info(cat_id) values('". $v ."')");
    }
}
```

Below is the submit portion of my code.

```
<form id="add_tweet_form" action="<?=$u?>admin/submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$user_info->id_str?>" name="twitid">
</form>
<form id="go_back_to_user" action="submit" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="masud" name="username">
<input type="hidden" value="from_tweet" name="submit_username">
</form>
<nav>
<a class="btn float-right" onclick="document.forms['add_tweet_form'].submit();this.innerHTML='Submitting...';" href="javascript:;">Submit</a>
<a class="float-right nav-text gray" title="Don't submit tweet, and go back"  onclick="window.location.href='<?=$u?>admin/submit.php';" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: are you sure that $_POST['action'] == submit?  Can you verify that it does equal submit by outputing $_POST?

Comment: mayby `print_r($_POST)` helps verifying the info

Comment: let me see ill see what it shows

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use variable variables. (`$$k = $v;`) They are impossible to debug, extremely confusing, and in this case, look like a great way to open up an SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 1):

mayby make this line:

```
if($_POST and $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){
```

to something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submit'){
```

The forms:

```
<form id="add_tweet_form" action="<?=$u?>admin/submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$user_info->id_str?>" name="twitid"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="submitted" name="PostAction" />
</form>
<form id="go_back_to_user" action="submit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="masud" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" value="from_tweet" name="submit_username">
</form>
<nav>
    <a class="btn float-right" onclick="document.forms['add_tweet_form'].submit();this.innerHTML='Submitting...';" href="javascript:;">Submit</a>
    <a class="float-right nav-text gray" title="Don't submit tweet, and go back"  onclick="window.location.href='<?=$u?>admin/submit.php';" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a>
```

The prosessing:

```
if($_POST['PostAction']) && $_POST['PostAction'] == 'submitted'){ 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST); // to see if the right info is posted...
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        $$k = $v;
    }
    foreach($cat as $k=>$v){
        if($v =='') continue;
        dbConnect("INSERT INTO twit_info(cat_id) values('". $v ."')");
        echo 'We have inserted something <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @soniccool As michael said, probaply the $_POST wont hold that action value. Also your using an form inside an form. That's no good practice. You can better make an hidde input type with an name like PostAction and value submit and check on that....

Comment: Actually his form is not inside a form here, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

add `<input type="hidden" name="add_tweet_form" value="true">`

then check `if(isset($_POST['add_tweet_form']) && $_POST['add_tweet_form']=='true')`